# Getting DataGrid current item into an object WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am having trouble casting WPF DataGrid's current item to a `linq-generated` entity since a few days. It would be amazing if someone can help me out of this one.
I am getting data for the DataGrid using linq query as below:

```
Dim payableexpense As New exprev
Dim listofexpenses As IEnumerable(Of exprev)

Private Sub txtsearchname_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) Handles txtsearchname.TextChanged
   listofexpenses = From expenses In db.exprevs
   Where expenses.school_id = currentschool.school_id AndAlso expenses.title.Contains(txtsearchname.Text.ToString) AndAlso expenses.status <> 1 AndAlso expenses.type = 1

   dgvsearchresults.ItemsSource = listofexpenses
   dgvsearchresults.Items.Refresh()
   stpexpensedetails.DataContext = payableexpense
End Sub
```

And for the DataGrid selection changed event, I have this code:

```
Private Sub dgvsearchresults_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles dgvsearchresults.SelectionChanged
payableexpense = dgvsearchresults.CurrentItem
End Sub
```

But during `run-time`, it is throwing an exception that:

> "unable to cast object of type 'ms.internal.namedobject' to 'exprev'"

At another place in my project, the same approach is working fine.

Comment: What is `exprev` ? Show us the code regarding `exprev`

Comment: @zackraiyan exprev is a Linq-to-SQL generated entity based on a table in Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `TryCast` method to try to cast the `SelectedItem` property to an `exprev`:

```
Private Sub dgvsearchresults_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles dgvsearchresults.SelectionChanged
    Dim selectedItem As exprev = TryCast(dgvsearchresults.SelectedItem, exprev)
    If selectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
        payableexpense = selectedItem
        '...
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You this is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for not marking it as and answer earlier.